# How can I find the height and width from 2 coordinates of longitude and latitude?

Tags: visual-c++, coordinates, width, formula

I looked online but couldn't find any results. My question is I have the coordinates of two points as seen in the image. But I need to find the height and width. I will write the code for c++ but if you don't have it you don't need to do it. I would be very grateful if you could just help me with the formula. Thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.

```
double lla2flatDistanceFormula(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
double psio = 30;
double href = 0;

const double R = 6378137;
const double f = 0.00335281066474748071;

// target
const double lat_p = lat1 * M_PI / 180;
const double lon_p = lon1 * M_PI / 180;
const double alt_p = href;

// reference
const double lat_o = lat2 * M_PI / 180;
const double lon_o = lon2 * M_PI / 180;

psio = psio * M_PI / 180;

double d_lat = abs(lat_p - lat_o);
double d_lon = abs(lon_p - lon_o);

double ff = (2.0 * f) - pow(f, 2);
double sin_lat = sin(lat_o);

double Rn = R / sqrt(1 - (ff * pow(sin_lat, 2)));
double Rm = Rn * (1 - ff) / (1 - ff * pow(sin_lat, 2));


double d_north = d_lat / atan2(1, Rm); //Height metric
double d_east = d_lon / atan2(1, (Rn * cos(lat_o))); //Width metric

 // Rotate matrix clockwise
double x_p = (d_north * cos(psio)) + d_east * sin(psio);
double y_p = (-d_north * sin(psio)) + d_east * cos(psio);
double z_p = -alt_p - href;

double w_p = sqrt(pow(x_p, 2) + pow(y_p, 2));



return w_p; //point to point distance metric }
```